# Congruence $mod\, p$, $ak = e*r$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have this question and I do not know where to start. A hint (and not a full solution) would be greatly appreciated!

Suppose p is an odd prime,  $a \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, for each $k = 1, 2, ... , \frac{p-1}{2}$, define $\epsilon_k, r_k$ by $a*k \equiv \epsilon_k * r_k \pmod{p}$, where $0 < r_k < \frac{p}{2}$ and $\epsilon_k = \pm 1$.

Show that $a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv (-1)^M$, where $M = \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 + ... + \epsilon_{(p-1)/2}$.

I think that maybe the congruence $a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ if $a$ is a square could help, but I do not see how.
I also know that $f: \mathbb{U}_p \mapsto \mathbb{U}_p, a \mapsto a*k$ is a bijection.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: That can't be correct. The rhs of what you want to prove should probably be $\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}{\epsilon_k}$, and while this is $(-1)^M$ for some $M$, that $M$ is not simply the sum of the $\epsilon_k$.

Comment: Ooh okay, the statement does say that we might have to salvage it. I will try what you said then and try to find a counter example.